# Getting rid of console output when freezing Python programs using Pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have recently written a fairly simple program for my grandfather using Python with GUI from Tkinter, and it works beautifully for what he will be using it for. However, there is, of course, the ugly console output window. I have successfully gotten rid of it by simply changing the extension of the file from .py to .pyw. When I freeze it using PyInstaller, it reappears again! Is there any way for me to fix this?

Comment: related: [Python - how can i hide the windows command prompt screen when the script is running?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24799155/4279)

Answer (score 132, accepted):

If you want to hide the console window, [here](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#windows-and-mac-os-x-specific-options) is the documentation:
This is how you use the `--noconsole` option

```
python pyinstaller.py --noconsole yourscript.py
```

If you need help using pyinstaller to get to the point where you need to use the `--noconsole` option [here](http://excid3.com/blog/pyinstaller-a-simple-tutorial/#.Ud7dwPm1FqA) is a simple tutorial for getting there.

Comment: I am not printing anything to the console window anyway, so this doesn't help. Thanks for trying.

Comment: "there is, of course, the ugly console output window" did you mean you want to close it? or prevent it from opening? if so I misunderstood

Comment: yes, That's what I meant. Would `os.system('exit')` work, or would that just close the program?

Comment: @dfreeze no, click on the link in my edit and control-f for "--noconsole" For a detailed guide

Comment: Note that the `--no-console` switch doesn't have any effect on *NIX systems.

Answer (score 26):

Just add the `--noconsole` flag:

```
$ python pyinstaller.py --noconsole yourprogram.py
```

You might want to use `--onefile` as well, which creates a single `.exe` file instead of a folder.

Comment: I am running PyInstaller 2.0, which means I simply type `python pyinstaller.py MYCODE.pyw` into cmd in the correct directory and it does the rest for me, including making the `.spec` file. Do I need to interrupt the program somewhere and execute this line? If so, how?

Comment: Thanks for --onefile suggestion @Blender.
$ python pyinstaller.py --noconsole --onefile yourprogram.py

Answer (score 18):

This is one of the first things that comes up in a search for this info, so I'd like to add what I found for release 3.2 of pyinstaller.  If you've already packaged your script by running

```
pyinstaller --onefile your_script.py
```

or similar, you can edit the your_script.spec file to rid yourself of the console.

```
    exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          name='main',
          debug=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True )
```

Simply change the console value to False.  Then run:

```
pyinstaller your_script.spec
```

Additionally, if you make changes to your code, run the above command to have them reflected in the your_script.exe.  I have found this useful for debugging various other issues.

Comment: --noconsole didn't work for me, but changing the spec file did. Thank you.

Comment: changing spec file did not worked in my case, at least reversing, making True, window taceback and debug =True

Answer (score 5):

```
Pyinstaller -F --noconsole yourfilename.pyw
```

This will create a single .exe file

```
Pyinstaller --noconsole yourfilename.pyw
```

Using this you will get the .exe file along with all .dll and other necessary files in a folder.

Comment: I thought there was no way to get just a single .exe! Thank you very much +1

Comment: What does the -F flag stands for ?

Comment: -F stands for onefile, this command creates a one-file bundled executable. 
See the full documentation.
https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html

Answer (score 3):

This command works fine

```
pyinstaller -F -w yourfilename.py
```

This hides the black console window.

Answer (score 1):

When you run your python script for executing the .exe file with pyintaller you would try this command to get rid of console window.

```
pyinstaller --onefile -w your_script.py
```