# How to hide the python console window in Pyinstaller

Tags: python, process, background, hide, pyinstaller

I used pyinstaller -F in order to create one .exe file to run.
I would like it to run in as a background process.
That means that if one clicks the .exe file, he can only close it from the "PROCESSES".
I want the program will run in the background and will not be seen. (As opposed to now, where I see the black console.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to hide console window in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/764631/how-to-hide-console-window-in-python)

Comment: you can use --noconsole option.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17584698/getting-rid-of-console-output-when-freezing-python-programs-using-pyinstaller

Comment: @TuiPopenoe No, this is for pyinstaller

Answer (score 5):

I think this will help you.

pyinstaller "filename.filetype" -w -F