# How to run a Python process in background?

Tags: python, terminal

I have a python script that is supposed to be running in the background. I used `pyinstaller` to create an executable file for the script. Now, this file opens up a terminal window. I don't have anything that is going to be printed on the terminal window, so I want it to close up just after starting up the process. How can I do that? Right now I just have a continous loop like this:

```
while True:
    myFunction()
    time.sleep(some-arbitrary-timeout-value)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can launch your script and detach it from the terminal console by :

- on linux you can use nohup & :   `nohup python your_executable.py &`
- on windows you can look at [nohup on windows on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3382082/whats-the-nohup-on-windows)

Comment: I found the answer. here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30710725/how-to-hide-the-python-console-window-in-pyinstaller

Comment: @Vedant Jumle,   good for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the context given, I will give you several options here for you to choose:

- `python pyinstaller.py --noconsole yourscript.py`
  You won't see the console window when executing your file.
- `nohup python your_executable.py &` Keeps the script running even if you close the terminal
- `pythonw test.py` similar to nohup, [works on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9706045/10230104)

Comment: i found the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30710725/how-to-hide-the-python-console-window-in-pyinstaller