# Running the program without running command prompt (visibly)

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, pyinstaller

I've made a program in python/tkinter, used pyinstaller to make a standalone executable (.exe). However, when i run it command prompt opens as well as the program. 
Is the issue with python or pyinstaller?

Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: have you tried the [`--noconsole`](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/usage.html#windows-and-mac-os-x-specific-options) command?

Comment: I used [cx freeze](https://pypi.org/project/cx_Freeze/) to compile my exe for python and it works fine with no command prompt.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting rid of console output when freezing Python programs using Pyinstaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17584698/getting-rid-of-console-output-when-freezing-python-programs-using-pyinstaller)

Comment: You can also try changing extension `.py` to `.pyw`.

Answer (score 0):

Just add --windowed or --noconsole to your pyinstaller statement:

```
    pyinstaller --windowed script.py
```