# changing output from integrated terminal VSCode to windows cmd prompt

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have a python script that automates some excel work for me.  I'm currently using VSCode.

I've installed PyInstaller and created a .exe file which runs the script.

I'd like to open a windows cmd prompt and print `completed` or the likes.

When I run this from VSCode it outputs to the integrated terminal - no problem.  From the .exe file nothing shows...

I'd like a way to open a separate (none integrated window) and print some text if anyone could point me in the right direct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `--console` or `-c` option when running pyinstaller for your script. More info [here](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#windows-and-mac-os-x-specific-options).

This allows you to show console window and you can use `print` statements in your script.

Example:

```sh
pyinstaller --console myscript.py
```

---

If you have already built an .exe, you can update the .spec file..

You would need to add `console=True` parameter to the `EXE` method, example:

```py
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          name='main',
          debug=False,
          strip=False,
          console=True)
```

and then run:

```sh
pyinstaller your_script.spec
```

---

Related links:

https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/6b8s7c/will_the_effects_of_print_statements_be_visible/

[Getting rid of console output when freezing Python programs using Pyinstaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17584698/getting-rid-of-console-output-when-freezing-python-programs-using-pyinstaller)

https://github.com/chriskiehl/Gooey/issues/235

Comment: worked like a treat, just needed to add `input("Press To Continue")` to bottom of code to ensure window stayed visible to user.  Thanks a lot