# Python: hide CMD in background

Tags: python, cmd

This is my first time creating an application, so I'm not exactly sure what I did wrong. How do I remove or hide this command prompt appearing every time I launch the converted python in exe?

[image: python]

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17584847/10987432

Comment: this question solution is already given on [How to hide console window in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/764631/how-to-hide-console-window-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Guys for the link. This works for me:
"edit the your_script.spec file to rid yourself of the console.

```
exe = EXE(pyz,
      a.scripts,
      a.binaries,
      a.zipfiles,
      a.datas,
      name='main',
      debug=False,
      strip=False,
      upx=True,
      console=True )
```

Simply change the console value to False. Then run:

pyinstaller your_script.spec"

SOURCE: [Getting rid of console output when freezing Python programs using Pyinstaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17584698/getting-rid-of-console-output-when-freezing-python-programs-using-pyinstaller)