# Is there a way to minimize the command prompt when you convert a python file to exe

Tags: python, pyinstaller, executable

I'm working on a python file that I want to convert to an executeable; which works great, the problem is when i open it it automatically opens a command prompt window; is there a way to code in something that closes the command prompt window without stopping the program?

Comment: Of course you can, this question has already been answered [here][1]. [1]:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17584698/getting-rid-of-console-output-when-freezing-python-programs-using-pyinstaller

Comment: use --windowed while converting