# how to convert python scripts to a exe build?

Tags: python, c++, c

how do I convert my python scripts of a pygame game to a exe without using pyinstaller because while using pyinstaller a pop up terminal come out, how can we create a standard exe build of this scripts? what about python embed in c/c++ ? if any one know how to do that please help me :)

Comment: There are ways to stop the pop-up terminal. Consult the `pyinstaller` documentation. Look for the option `noconsole`. You can't have what you consider a *standard exe build* because Python is not a compiled language and so your Python program cannot be directly represented in machine code. Wrapping your Python program in an executable is considerably more complex than you seem to imagine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting rid of console output when freezing Python programs using Pyinstaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17584698/getting-rid-of-console-output-when-freezing-python-programs-using-pyinstaller)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to stick to pyinstaller and add the `--noconsole` command line argument, like this:

```sh
pyinstaller --noconsole yourscript.py
```

to not have a pop-up terminal.
*But*, if you're stubborn, you can use [nuitka](https://github.com/Nuitka/Nuitka), an application that converts python to c++, which embeds a python implementation, producing *pretty* large executables.