# Black Window in PyInstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I'm using PyInstaller to make python-exe's out of my scripts and the exe's work, but every time I execute one of the PyInstaller-exe's a black window pops up. It is pitchblack and looks like a command prompt, but you can't type in it and it disappears as soon as the exe is finished. I want to get rid of it but I don't know how. I've looked on the official website but there is nothing.

Ps: Sorry for eventual spelling- and grammar-mistakes

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is a console window. Please look again in the documentation at the linked chapter. It is definitely there: https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#windows-and-mac-os-x-specific-options

For some more comments about that, look here: [Getting rid of console output when freezing Python programs using Pyinstaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17584698/getting-rid-of-console-output-when-freezing-python-programs-using-pyinstaller)